# Number theory proof by counter example

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of two cycles of lengths $r$ and $s$ respectively whose product does not have order $lcm(r,s)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $(1\ 2)$ and $(1\ 2)$? They have lengths $2$ and $2$ but their product has order $1 \neq \operatorname{lcm}(2, 2) = 2$.

Comment: I guess .. that works ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(r\;r+1\;r+2\;\ldots\;r+s-1\;1)(1\;2\;\ldots\;r)=(1\;2\;\ldots\;r+s-1)$, which has order $r+s-1$. Note that this equals the lcm only if $r=1$ or $s=1$, in which case no counterexample is possible.

Comment: how about transposition (1 2) and (2 3)?

Comment: That's only for the special case $r=s=2$ (and is in fact covered by my example). My construction works for any $r,s>1$ .